# Wget public s3 bucket

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wget

I'd like to download all of the files in [this public s3 bucket](https://s3.amazonaws.com/halitereplaybucket/) **without an AWS access key** (since this is part of a tutorial that others have to follow). Each of the constituent files ([example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/halitereplaybucket/1475594084-2235734685.hlt)) can be downloaded individually.

Comment: You have `aws cli` installed? It is very simple if you have AWS CLI.

Comment: @helloV Doesn't that require an API key?

Comment: what do you call AWS API key ? to use aws cli you need to have a access key from AWS ? so you need to have an account

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Yes. I want to download the bucket without an access key.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use an Access Key from an AWS account (eg signup a new one), even if no particular permissions have been assigned to that account by the bucket owner? It would be totally within your control, not requiring somebody else to do anything. That way, you could use the[AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not taking an easy road:

1. you will need to get the key (i.e. files) in the bucket

you can use [rest API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) and make a request as follow

```
    curl -H "GET /?list-type=2 HTTP/1.1" \
    -H "Host: halitereplaybucket.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: 20161025T124500Z" \
    -H "Content-Type: text/plain" https://halitereplaybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

This will return a response in xml format with the contents and all keys from the bucket.

2. You will need to parse the response and extract all keys
3. for each of the keys, you can make a request to download the file

   ```
   wget 'http://halitereplaybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/{file}'
   ```

I understand you mention you do not want to use a AWS key but using the CLI it will be as simple as

```
aws s3 sync s3://halitereplaybucket .
```

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP... You can use the `aws s3 sync` command with *ANY* AWS Credentials because the bucket is publicly-readble. That is definitely the easiest way to go. See: [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but the credentials have to be valid and the OP doesn't have one.